# Python function validation with multiple booleans

Tags: python

I'm trying to define a function that will validate password for a new user, which has to validate if it contains at least 8 characters, at least one upper case and at least one letter.

That's the code I've got so far:

```
def password():
    length = False
    uppercase = False
    
    while length and uppercase == False:
        result = input('Please create a password with minimum 8 characters, at least one upper case letter and at least one number: ')
        if len(result) < 8:
            print('Sorry, your password is too short')
        else:
            length = True
```

I have also figured out already how to validate upper case and number presence in string with following:

```
has_uppercase = any(c.isupper() for c in str1)
has_digit = any(d.isdigit() for d in str2)
```

The question is how can I plot multiple condition into one function so it returns the result only once everything is correct?

Comment: Sorry, I've just noticed an error in line 5. Of course I've meant to write:
while length and uppercase == False:

Comment: Set up your function to have a series of checks, such that only successful cases can proceed through them all; when you have a valid input, you can `break` out of the loop or directly `return`

Comment: `while length and uppercase == False:` is interpreted as `while (length) and (uppercase == False):`. Since both `length` and `uppercase` are `False` this is `while (False) and (False  == False):`. That is evaluated to `while (False) and (True):` and then boils down to `while False:`. So your `while` loop never runs.

Answer (score 0):

You can check each condition sequentially, and give the user helpful messages when they fail.

Here I'm using a while loop to make sure the function keep on trying if the user fails (you can set a max number of tries if you want). After asking for an input, the function check for each condition. If any fail, we `continue` to restart the while loop. At the end of the while loop (when all conditions have passed), we have a good password and can `break` out of the loop.

```py
def password():
    while True:
        result = input('Please create a password with minimum 8 characters, at least one upper case letter and at least one number: ')
        if len(result) < 8:
            print('Sorry, your password is too short')
            continue
        if not any(c.isupper() for c in result):
            print('Sorry, your password needs an upper case letter.')
            continue
        if not any(d.isdigit() for d in result):
            print('Sorry, your password needs a number.')
            continue
        break
    return result
```